# How to pass an array of files as an argument

Tags: c, function, pthreads

I am struggling to pass an array of files as an argument to pthread_create function.

```
FILE *arqvs[arq];
  for(int i=1, count=0;i<=arq;i++, count++){
    changeName(file, i); //change the name of the file based on the index
    arqvs[count] = fopen(file, "r");
    
    if(arqvs[count]==NULL){
      printf("Erroro:(\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
```

The code above shows how I am creating the array and opening the files in "r" mode. I have done some tests and it seems to work well. Is reads all the files based on the number of the variable **arq**.
The problem comes out when I try to pass the array to the function pthread_create as mentioned above..

Here's the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<trd; i++){
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, funcao, &**arqvs);
  }
```

And here's the function:

```
void * funcao(void * args){
  char voto[2];
  FILE *** fileName = (FILE***) args;
  while (fgets(voto, sizeof(voto), *fileName[0])) {
  printf("%s", voto); 
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

This code does not work, and I dont know why. It has been awhile since I programmed in C, so, I would appreciate any hints or answers.

Comment: @Barmar Variable Good hint, thank you. I use **i** to change the name of the archive, and count is only the index of the array of files. I only need one of them in fact. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, now I see -- one counts from 1, the other from 0. You can just count from 0, and use `i+1` for the filename part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the array directly, there's no need to use `&`. Arrays automatically decay to a pointer when used as function arguments.

```
for(int i=0;i<trd; i++){
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, funcao, arqvs);
}
void * funcao(void * args){
  char voto[2];
  FILE **fileName = args;
  while (fgets(voto, sizeof(voto), fileName[0])) {
    printf("%s", voto); 
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, arrays are usually passed to functions/threads by passing a pointer to the first element of the array. If the length is unknown to the called function/thread, then an additional parameter is often passed which specifies the number of elements in the array.

If the number of elements in the array (which is the value of `arq`) is known to both threads, then you only need to pass a pointer to the first element of the array. Otherwise, you will also have to pass the number of elements in the array to `pthread_create`, for example by instead passing a pointer to a `struct` which also contains this information.

Assuming that the number of elements in the array does not have to be passed, you should change the line

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, funcao, &**arqvs);
```

to

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, funcao, arqvs);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, funcao, &arqvs[0]);
```

This is because the array `arqvs` automatically [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) to a pointer to the first element of the array when used in this context.

Since the array's element type is `FILE *` and a pointer to the first element of the array has been passed to the function `funcao`, this means that the type of the passed pointer is `FILE **`. Therefore, you should change the line

```
FILE *** fileName = (FILE***) args;
```

to:

```
FILE ** fileName = (FILE**) args;
```

Also, `fileName` does not seem like an appropriate name for this pointer. A better name would be something like `files` or `streams`.

Answer (score 1):

The value (`&**argvs`) you're passing in to `pthread_create` is a `FILE *`.  But then in `funcao`, you are casting it to a `FILE ***` which is not the same, so everything breaks (undefined behavior).

You need to make sure the value you pass in and the value you cast the `void *` to are the same type.  In your case, it probably makes the most sense to use `FILE **`.  So you can call pthread_create as:

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, funcao, arqvs);
```

and in funcao, use it as:

```
FILE ** files = (FILE**) args;
```

Note that `arq` (the size of the array) is lost when you convert the array to a pointer, so you have no good way of knowing how many `FILE *`s there are in funcao.  It may make more sense to create a `struct` that holds both the (pointer to the) array and the array size, and pass a pointer to that to the thread function.